# Set focus to other jframe

Tags: java, swing

My question is related about java swing frame. I have a 2 jFrame. jFrame1 and jFrame2. there is a jbutton is in the jframe 1 so when user click the jbutton I want to focus to frame 2(Frame 2 is already loaded in the application.) without closing frame1.   Please help to do this

Comment: Use modal dialogs! Also, see this question [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: Don't know that the JDialog needs to be modal, but yes you should be using a JDialog as a child Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Window.toFront()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toFront%28%29) to bring the current frame to front:

```java
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public MyFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("Bring other MyFrame to front");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame("1");
        new MyFrame("2");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (Window window : Window.getWindows()) {
            if (this != window) {
                window.toFront();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the 'right answer to the wrong question'.  See comments.